Assign DNS name to a container in Synology SRM for Router?
How do I assign a DNS name to a container in Synology SRM for Routers ?

What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate a minimum of self-effort at this point.

Having spoken to you on your other question (now deleted) I think you should be asking "How do I configure DNS names for my LAN using a <insert router make/model here>?". creating the DNS entries is prerequisite to configuring the reverse proxy that will eventually allow you to connect to the containers based on their port using only a DNS name. without the router make/model however, no one can provide any specific assistance to you.

I understand, this is going to take some time to ask questions oriented around how this site operates.
The router make and model to which I'm using is the Synology WRX560.

Are you clients already configured to use the syno router's dns service? have you already configured the routers DNS to forward queries to a public DNS server?

I don't understand your question ?

lets say your client wants to go to superuser.com. does it ask your router what IP is associated with the name superuser.com or does it ask another dns server like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8? if you are a windows user you can run ipconfig /all and look at the "DNS Servers" in the result to see what the system is configured to use. does it show your routers IP address under "DNS Servers"?

When running ipconfig /all it shows identical to that of 1.1.1.1 & 9.9.9.9

is your windows client configured to use DHCP to obtain its IP address and DNS servers? have you installed and configured DHCP on the router?

@Christopher, please edit and improve your question, every time a question is asked in comments, instead of replying with all the details in the comments.  This is because comments may get deleted.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle
What I want to accomblish is, first when using DNS server on my router; I'm asked what kind of zone I want to pick. At this point I just t picked any zone that I deemed would work. Although one thing I excluded was the name before the post the domain. In other words, I supplied the DNS Server the domain, but didn't include the name I would like have before the domain. As I wasn't aware that I can just give it any name, unless I'm wrong ?
I've given most of that which I know for how to get this resolved. I'm trying to understand and fix my mistakes.

@Christopher, after you have created a Forward lookup zone, you can add an A record in it pointing to your container server. at this point you will still need to use port numbers. I'm working on an answer, though i'm having more difficulty finding help resources on creating forwarders from the SRM product (though there is copious information on how to do it in DSM). once I find that I'll try to post somthing. that said i do need you to answer the question I asked about whether your clients are using the router for DHCP.

@FrankThomas I created a Forward Zone in SRM which is in Synology Router. If I understand correctly, I have to now create an A record in my domain DNS record that points to the containers IP. I assume that name I give the A record is whatever name I choose for the container ? Although must it have to include the domain as well ?

yes the A-rec should have the name you want to give to that container (perhaps synchThing?) but should Not have the full name of the domain. the zone is a container, and all things in the zone will have its domain name. so for instance in the zone foo, I might create an A rec "bar" and when queried it will come out as "Bar.Foo". then you give it the IP of the container server.

The thing i haven't found doc for, is called "forwarders" configuration. so all your clients will be configured to look to your router for DNS, and if the name requested is in a zone that server carries, it will reply with the IP address on the A rec. however if you query for superuser.com, your server doesn't have a zone for that, so it needs to be configured with server IPs to forward queries on to if it can't answer them (the 1.1.1.1/9.9.9.9 we discussed earlier this week). Do you see an option in your DNS server, above the "zone level" for "Forwarders"?

@FrankThomas
When you say, and if the name requested is in a zone that server carries. Do you mean, the name given in the DNS record ?
When creating the Zone for the DNS Server, I created a forward zone although there are two policies, Forward first & Forward Only. I left it at Forward first. I think that answers your question but to add to that, there is an option which is the option I chose to create a forward zone.

so the terminology is confusing here. you want a Primary Zone of type Forward Zone, rather than a "forwarding Zone". its very confusing. A What synology calls a "forwarding zone" is what other vendors call "conditional forwarders" but that is not what you need. Delete that zone, and create a new Primary Zone following the instructions in my half-formed answer.

@FrankThomas Is a forward zone, a Forward Zone must be a Master Zone. Although what is a Master DNS server ?

so I'm gonna ask you to understand that you have a router with enterprise-grade features, that you completely don't need to care about, because you are just trying to host a DNS zone for your LAN on a single server. I don't know where you got the word "master" but when multiple DNS servers host a single domain, one of them is generally "Authorative" (its the one defined in the zone definition) and every other DNS server that hosts that zone hosts a replica of it, which returns a "non-authoritative" response to queries on that domain. you have a single server that is private to your LAN.

@FrankThomas You mentioned that I must create a Primary Zone of type Forward. Although in the DNS Server for the router under Zones there is no such type of Primary Zone, only that of Master, Slave, Forward & Import.
If I choose Master Zone,  there is a drop down for Forward Zone, that is why I mentioned; must I choose Master Zone ?
Proceeding that, there is Domain name, which I understand is that of the domain I want to use and proceeding that is Master DNS Server and then serial type which is set to by default, Integer. Although that can be changed too a date.

Then it will be master, but that is very different from the synology documentation. https://kb.synology.com/en-me/SRM/help/DNSServer/dns_server_zone_mng?version=1_3  Also note, I did not say anything about the settings you probably don't need to care about. I'm not going to describe every one of them. if you only have one DNS server, serial format is just a matter of taste.

It is different then from the Synology documentation. Although first question or hopefully two. What if I want the port number removed ?

This is not a discussion forum. Your question hasn't improved with any of the details in the comments.

I don't understand, must I start a new question if I don't want to use port numbers or can I append it to this question ?

so getting rid of the port numbers is what the reverse proxy is for. but yes, you need to add that as a seperate question, to avoid being "too broad" or asking multiple questions in one. note that you have not provided us any indication as to whether the DNS is now working.

What Enterprise features does this router have if possible in brief ?
As well, what is the difference between doing this exact same thing which tutorials exist on the NAS, compared to Router ?

First a couple notes:
This answer will heavily reference the following Synology support links:

Synoology Knowledge Center: SRM DNS

Synology Knowledge Center: DHCP server


The goal here is to access the container via a domain name, but clients will still require ports be specified to access the container's services. Later you may choose to utilize a reverse proxy to eliminate the need for port specification.
The process will consist of several steps:

Configure Forwarding and Create a DNS Forward Zone for your domain
Add an A Rec within that zone that points to your container's IP address.
Configure the routers DHCP server to provide its LAN IP as your client's DNS server.

Configuring Forwarders:
From the SRM DNS Server controls,

check the box labeled Enable resolution services
Enable Limit source IP service
Configure Source IP List by adding your lan subnet (eg: 192.168.5.0/24)
Enable Enable forwarders
Configure Forwarders, by setting Forwarder1 to 1.1.1.1 and Forwarder2 to 9.9.9.9

more information on configuring forwarders can be found here: https://kb.synology.com/en-nz/SRM/help/DNSServer/dns_server_resolve_mng?version=1_3
Create a Forward Lookup Zone:
From the SRM DNS Server Zones controls,

Click Create
Select Primary Zone
Under Domain Type, select Forward Zone
Under Primary DNS Server, enter the IP of the routers LAN interface. The synology instructions assume that you intend to run a publically accessible DNS server, but that is not the case here.
Set Limit Zone Transfer to your LAN subnet.
enable Limit Source IP and add your LAN subnet to Source IP List
Click OK to save the settings and create the zone.

More details on configuring a zone can be found here: https://kb.synology.com/en-me/SRM/help/DNSServer/dns_server_zone_mng?version=1_3
Create an A record for your Container

Select your zone, and click Edit
Select Resource Record
Select A Record
Enter a name for the record. This will be the name of your container. Do not include the name of the domain. It will be inferred from its parent zone.
Enter the IP address of your container server.
Click OK to save the record.

Testing your new DNS server

On one of your systems, open a command prompt
Enter nslookup <containername>.<domainname> <Router LAN IP address> replacing everything in angle braces (<>) with the values you have configured. Press Enter to execute the command.
if successful, the nslookup command will display the IP address of your container server. If it displays an error, please review your zone and A record configuration.
In the command prompt, enter nslookup superuser.com <Router LAN IP address>. Press Enter to execute the command.
if successful, the nslookup command will display the IP address for superuser.com. if it displays an error, please review the Forwarder configuration.

Configuring DHCP to set clients to use your new DNS server
Its likely that your router is already configured to be a DHCP server for your LAN. if not, please refer to this document for how to set it up: https://kb.synology.com/en-us/SRM/help/SRM/NetworkCenter/lan_network_dhcp?version=1_3

Configure your DHCP server, by removing both the Primary DNS and Secondary DNS setting's values.
Enter your routers LAN IP address in Primary DNS. Leave Secondary DNS empty.
Click OK to save the changes.
On each of your network clients, ensure that they are configured to obtain their IP addresses and DNS addresses from DHCP. Then reboot the client.

Wrapping up
Now, you should be able to access your container using a path like containerName.DomainName:portnumber
To test, use a command like this one in windows Powershell:
test-netconnection containername.domainname -p portnumber
if it succeeds in the TCP test, then everything is working fine with DNS.
If your container is serving content using HTTPS additional configuration will be required inside the container, like certificate generation/installation, webserver configuration to use that certificate, etc. Enter another question for topics like that
